# Hide page title in Wordpress 3.0

Tags: customization, pages

I can't find the option to hide the page title. Is there some other plugin required to get this functionality?

If you look in this video [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q16NcSm99M&feature=player_embedded) you can see the option to set the page title. I don't have this option.

I'm not looking for a code solution here, I need something which will allow end users to hide the title.

Comment: The video linked is for the Headway theme, are you using the Headway theme?

Comment: It's a theme-dependant feature as t31os said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the videos shows options that come with the headway theme, in order to see them you must use the headway theme. 
it's not a build in functionality of WordPress, however you can use the_title filter to replace or remove the title for a specific post based on custom fields values like so:

```
function my_title_filter($title){
    global $post;
    $custom_t = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_title', true);
    if (empty($custom_t){
        return $title;
    }else{
        if ($custom_t == 'remove'){
            return '';
        }else{
            return $custom_t;
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_title_filter' );
```

and after you add this code to your theme's functions.php file
all you need to do is edit the post/page you want to replace or remove the title and create a custom filed named "my_title" and enter your "new title" or "remove"
to remove completely.

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Just tried this, but the custom fields don't allow you to put a null value in them. Putting in a nbsp; results in a linked nbsp; on the front-end.

Comment: why would you put null value? to replace just type the new title, to remove just "remove" and if you don't want to change then don't do anything.