# Hide a page title in Wordpress 3.0

Tags: title

I can't find the option to hide the page title. Is there some other plugin required to get this functionality?

If you look in this video [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q16NcSm99M&feature=player_embedded) you can see the option to set the page title. I don't have this option.

I'm not looking for a code solution here, I need something which will allow end users to hide the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide page title in Wordpress 3.0](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/hide-page-title-in-wordpress-3-0)

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that's a tutorial video for a premium theme called http://headwaythemes.com.

Answer (score 1):

The video you have linked to is meant for the users of the Headway Themes. There is no option within WordPress itself to hide the title of pages. The video itself also does not show you how to hide the actual title, the option referred to is actually to hide the page from your navigation. If this is what you want to do you can quite easily hide any specific page from your menus in the custom menus page by simply removing the relevant page from your menu.

Comment: +1, but later in the video there's a meta box with a checkbox that allows exactly what he's asking for. See Video 0:48 min.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new page template ([wp codex page template link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)) and exclude the Pages Title ([wp codex link page title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)).

- Just copy the page template
- Look for and remove `<?php wp_title(); ?>`
- Add the new page title to the top `<?php
  /*
  Template Name: New Page Name
  */
  ?>`
- Save it
- Select the new page template to exclude the title on certain pages

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) with a checkbox inside (this would be done through your `functions.php` file). Then you have to put the [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function inside your `single.php` or ex. `index.php` files loop and `echo` your `wp_title()` based on the `if/else` condition of the meta value (`(bool) true/false || 0/1`.